# Error while setting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permision in manifest - Unknow attribute android:name

Tags: android, attributes, manifest

I'm developing an Android app with Android studio.

I've been trying to set some permissions into my manifest file in order to write some file to the external storage everything following the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="timetracker.iuandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

          ..... and some more tags .....
```

The problem is that manifest is telling me that "android:name" is an unknow attribute, and if I remove it, of course, it tells me that a name attribute is needed, so I can't create a new file in my app because of this permission problem

Is there somethign I'm missing? or something deprecated not shown at the tutorial?

I can't post Images due to my low reputation sorry but the error goes throgh every android:name= and android:name= tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be multiple issues with your `AndroidManifest` file. First, a `Java` `Package` is usually declared like the following:

`com.domain.package`

So your declaration should be `com.iuandroid.timetracker`.

Secondly, the `maxSdkVersion` in in the wrong spot. This...

```
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

should be in the `<uses-sdk/>` section, not between the permission tags. Your permissions are also declared incorrectly; it should be...

```
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PERMISSION"/>
```

instead of...

```
<android:uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PERMISSION"/>
```

Lastly, you are also missing a few closing tags. Your `AndroidManifest.xml` file should be as follows when formatted correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="timetracker.iuandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: yes that works Thanks!, I was dealing with permissions for the first time, the main thing was changing

`<android:uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PERMISSION"/>`

for 

`<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PERMISSION"/>`

btw on your answer you left the wrong permissions syntax